# Using GIT on Aptana 3 standalone

Tags: git, aptana-studio

The only references I see to GIT in Aptana Studio 3 (the standalone version) are under preferences where the only field is to identify an executable (do I need to do that?) and importing a project, where it asks for a repository uri. I see nowhere to configure user information for a particular repository, and, if I need to install a plugin, nowhere to do that.

Comment: Yeah I think the documentation for GIT and Aptana is lacking, to say the least. I've installed GIT and Aptana, and if I didn't have a little bit of GIT background I think trying to use these 2 programs together would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 12):

Under App Explorer section there should be a gear icon, click on that, then click initialize git...

Comment: This works for example when you migrate workspace from eclipse with exiting projects that use git.

Comment: @Tom And how do you remove git from a project?

Comment: remove the .git folder

Answer (score 1):

The following worked on my Mac OS:

Open Preferences → Team → Git and try to change the path of the "Git Executable" to `/usr/local/git/bin/git`.

On Windows, you'll find the preferences here: Window → Preferences → Team → Git.

Answer (score 0):

First question and, apologies if this is obvious, but have you installed Git on your system? On my Mac, I have/had to install Git first, before I could use it in Aptana.

Once you have verified that you have Git installed on your Win, Mac or 'Nix system, open Aptana and set the executable in the Git preference pane that you note in your question.

From this point, you should have Git options from Aptana. In the App Explorer view, there's a sprocket icon that, when clicked, will now give you Git options. Also, if you right-click on a file in your App Explorer, you'll have Git options available, too.

Comment: Thanks for that. Git was installed, but I hadn't identified the executable (discovering where that was wasn't without fun!) and now when I right click on a project I had set up as git through the command line, the team menu does indeed have git options. 


The other part is still perplexing me. To push it to another git, is it the create remote option? And if so, having not seen beyond the first screen where a uri is requested, is there a place for me to specify a (non-global) user id/pass ?

Comment: Did it from the command line. Never did find a dialog for it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the slow response! I did not realize I had messages (missed the icon in SO).

Comment: Whoops! Then I hit enter too soon :). Anyway, I have never been able to get the Remote Push to work right with Aptana's Git functionality. I need to log a ticket b/c, like you, 'Push' is never available, despite my having everything setup correctly. If you're on a Mac, check out Tower. It's a really, really cool Git client and I've been using it exclusively for the last week with no troubles!